# Set any folder as system folder?

Tags: onedrive, windows-8.1, special-locations

As of Windows 8.1, SkyDrive now has its own system folder. This manifests itself in two obvious ways:

1. SkyDrive gets its own treeview node in file explorer.
2. You can only move the folder, not delete it.

**The question**: is it possible to recreate this system folder behavior for other folders? In particular for Dropbox and Google Drive.

[image: Treeview]
[image: Location]